# Need help regarding .htaccess url rewriting for country specific subdirectory urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project for making a website which contains country specific urls, to make it more targeted and separate.

Here what i want:

1. open - domain.com and read this file index.php
2. when open domain.com/us/ and read this file country.php ( /us/ it can be anything like /de/   /in/   /uk/ means its dynamically generated country code based on request.
3. When open domain.com/us/free-free-free-ad1965.html ( its post on website with id 1965 from database, so its should read ad.php file.
4. if open domain.com/xyz  which does not exists it should give 404 error and read 404.php file same applies to domain.com/us/xyz

here is my current htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ country.php?countrycode=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&post=$2&id=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^maintenance\.html$  maintenance.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit\.html$  submit.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy\.html$  privacy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms\.html$  terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$  contact.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
```

after applying this htaccess option 1 works fine everytime and option 2 &3 & 4 is conflicting with each others. The all four options are seperate and should have to work with each other.

Please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How more specific the rule how further up it should be.

You should change the order.

> rewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&post=$2&id=$3
>   [NC]
>   Should probably be more up

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&post=$2&id=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ country.php?countrycode=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^maintenance\.html$  maintenance.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit\.html$  submit.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy\.html$  privacy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms\.html$  terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$  contact.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
```

Comment: Ok i tried it but no luck.     when requesting `http://www.domain.com/us/`    its giving `http://www.domain.com/country.php/?countrycode=country.php`    and when requesting `http://www.domain.com/us/free-free-free-ad1965.html`  i m getting error as:   The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Ok i think its working now, the issue was 301 redirect code line i changed its position back and now its working.       `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]`    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&post=$2&id=$3 [NC]`
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ country.php?countrycode=$1 [NC]`